# competing CSS stylesheets

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to remove the borders on a specific table:

```
<table class="teacher">
    <tr>
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td>col 1</td>
        <td>col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2</td>
        <td>col 1</td>
        <td>col 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can see my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R6X2M/1/)

I think the `bootstrap.css` is competing with my `site.css` but I'm not sure how to get rid of the borders?

Here is my teacher (from `site.css`) styling:

```
.teacher {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
}

.teacher table {
        border: none !important;
        border-collapse:collapse !important;
}

.teacher .contentLabel {
    width: 45%;
}

.teacher input {
    width: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.teacher textarea {
    width: 225px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

My bundle:

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/site.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-duallistbox.css",
            "~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css"));
```

I think this is what is causing this issue from bootstrap:

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.table > thead > tr > th,
.table > tbody > tr > th,
.table > tfoot > tr > th,
.table > thead > tr > td,
.table > tbody > tr > td,
.table > tfoot > tr > td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.table > thead > tr > th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}
.table > caption + thead > tr:first-child > th,
.table > colgroup + thead > tr:first-child > th,
.table > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > th,
.table > caption + thead > tr:first-child > td,
.table > colgroup + thead > tr:first-child > td,
.table > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > td {
  border-top: 0;
}
.table > tbody + tbody {
  border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
}
.table .table {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment out the border for `<td>` in **Line 94**.

```
td {
    color: #000;
    /* border: 1px solid #7c7c7b; */
    padding: .3em 1em;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Additional pieces of CSS to keep in mind if you ever use `<thead>` and `<th>` elements for tables:

**Line 103:**

```
th {
    color: #7c7c7b;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: large;
    text-align: center;
    /* border: 1px solid #7c7c7b; */
    padding: .3em 1em;
}
```

**Line 112:**

```
th.th2 {
    color: #7c7c7b;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: large;
    text-align: center;
    /* border: 1px solid #7c7c7b; */
    padding: .3em 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well on line 90 in the CSS of the jsfiddle you provided is

```
td {
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #7c7c7b;
    padding: .3em 1em;
    text-align: left;
}
```

that is what is causing the borders..

So the rule is on the `td` elements and not the `table`

Using

```
.teacher td{border:none;}
```

should solve it..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/R6X2M/2/